# Unexpected error Tracking number: c904462681469709

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

been trying to create a table in sandbox and i'm getting an "Unexpected error
Tracking number: c904462681469709". sometimes the table gets created, sometimes it doesn't.
any wizards that can help me with this?
cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today, I do not know what causes the error, but I found that BigQuery has loaded my table. The steps I used are as follows:

1. Click the three dot drop down to create the table.
2. Fill out the source, destination, schema for the table.
3. After clicking 'create table' receive the error and close out the error window.
4. Close out of the create table window.
5. Refresh your BigQuery page.
6. Check the dataset you created the table under and it should be there.

I hope this method works for you as it did for me!

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too. So strange but yes I did the same thing Devin did. Took me forever trying to figure it out but it is what it is. Just refresh and keep going.

Comment: this is not an answer. It should be a comment.